# getting rid of extra space that comes with android's default buttons

Tags: android, android-studio

I've placed three buttons side by side using constraints, with 4dp gap between each as shown below, but due to this *"extra space"*(shown below), the actual gap between buttons looks greater than it is:

[image: extra space button]

What is the attribute that android uses to maintain this space? How can I remove it. I'm using the default `<Button>` widget that is android's default button widget.

Comment: Try to use `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"`

Comment: @JohnLe, where do I add this property?

Comment: You can get rid of this by setting button's background a color (not backgroundTint).Like this -  android:background="@color/colorGrey"

Comment: In xml like `<Button style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">`

Comment: what's the difference between setting: `android:background` and `<button style=...>` ? I don't exactly know but just guessing, does the `android:background` property not make the border areas clickable? other wise it's probably best solution since setting the style seems to make the background transparent and setting color afterwards doesn't affect the button.

Comment: `background` only changes the `View`'s background. `style` changes the `View`'s style that will change multiple properties such as `textSize`, `textColor`, `background`, and so on. Extends and customize style: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#Customize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this attribute to the button`style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"`. This will make your button white and borderless. After add background to your button using this. `android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"`

Your button should be as below.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

Comment: addresses both the issues I mentioned in the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add Background to your Button and this space will cover by the background color.

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **translationX** and **translationY** property.